# Applying multiple textures to the same mesh like tiles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, texture-mapping

I've been working on procedural terrain generation in Unity for a while and I was wondering if there was a way to have multiple textures applied to a single mesh like tiles. Imagine a chess board with black and white areas designated on a single mesh and changed during run time. I've considered using multiple meshes but that will over-complicate another part of my program.

Comment: If you create submeshes, then you can assign a different material to each submesh. That's going to add some extra steps to your model import and/or mesh generation, though.

Comment: Thanks, I had not heard of sub-meshes but it looks like they fit my problem better than the alternatives i was considering.

Comment: huh? Where do I up vote this answer? UP VOTED!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use submeshes, you can [create a custom shader that will reference both textures and switch between them using any logic you desire](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaderExamples.html). Including tiles.